# Jquery history - Ajax navigation - How to make url request and search request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, navigation, history

I'm using the Jquery history 
exemple: mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html

I don't really know how to make a search query using a search box form and how to create a search link like:

mysearch.php?search=search+term&submit=1

Normal link are usually as follow: 
load 3

It's probably adding code to the function in the main page but i'm not to familliar with javascript

Thank you for your help

Comment: What? I dont' get it. mysearch.php?search=search+term&submit=1 is a form GET request. You tell me you don't know that? If yes, please read on basic HTML/CSS/Javascript first

Comment: Yeah, but to work with that ajax navigation system, i don't really know how tu put it all together

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form already, you can do something like:

```
var dataString=$("#searchForm").serialize();
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: getString,
  data: dataString,
blablahblah
```

Your question is a bit vague though, but serialize will create the parameters string for you.